# Memory/performance tradeoff when determining the size of a Perl hash

Tags: perl

I was browsing through some Perl code in a popular repositiory on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) and ran across this method to calculate the size of a hash:

> ```
> while ( my ($a, undef ) = each %h ) { $num++; }
> ```

I thought why would one go through the trouble of writing all that code when it could more simply be written as

```
$num = scalar keys %h;
```

So, I compared both methods with Benchmark.

```
my %h = (1 .. 1000);
    cmpthese(-10, {
        keys      => sub {
                             my $num  = 0;
                             $num = scalar keys %h;
                         },
        whileloop => sub {
                             my $num = 0;
                             while ( my ($a, undef ) = each %h ) {
                                 $num++;
                             }
                         },
});
```

```
 RESULTS
                Rate whileloop      keys
 whileloop    5090/s        --     -100%
 keys      7234884/s   142047%        --
```

The results show that using `keys` is MUCH faster than the while loop. My question is this: why would the original coder use such a slow method? Is there something that I'm missing? Also, is there a faster way?

Comment: the while loop also gives the wrong result if you happen to have called each on the hash before without exhausting or later resetting the iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot read the mind of whomever might have written that piece of code, but he/she likely thought:

```
my $n = keys %hash;
```

used more memory than iterating through everything using [`each`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#each).

Note that the scalar on the left hand side of the assignment creates scalar context: There is no need for `scalar` unless you want to create a scalar context in what would otherwise have been list context.

Answer (score 4):

Because he didn't know about `keys`'s ability to return the number of elements in the hash.